# XML Validation, Error Found

Tags: xml, validation, blogger

I have designed my own template for blogger , but on the following code bellow i have got errors which i did not figured out what has to be change, i know that some of the tags on XML is prey different to HTML .

```
<p>
    Cras justo odio, dapibus ac
    <a href="javascript:;" rel="tipsy" title="Example Tooltip">facilisis</a>
    in, egestas eget quam. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nullam quis risus eget urna
    <a href="javascript:;" rel="tipsy" title="An even longer tooltip! <br/> With more stuff!">mollis ornare</a>
    vel eu leo.
</p>
```

Comment: it says on the following line there is an error , and wont let me to validate the XML

Comment: On what line? What error? What is the actual error message that you are seeing?

Comment: http://s15.postimage.org/5vmmvgq9l/Screen_Shot_2012_06_10_at_22_47_04.png

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<` and `>` in your `title` attribute with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

Comment: but i cant see any open tag or close tag for title !! please display and correct me .

Comment: The value of your `title` attribute contains `<br/>`.

Comment: Yes :D Thank you does help. can you also tell me how do i close this link end tag, it gives error <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/base.css" />

Comment: What is the error message this time? And what column number is indicated?

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like you're closing your `<link>` element with `>` rather than with `/>`.

Comment: its been like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/base.css" /> and also tried like this > - still error